# Can any one help me with getting friends list

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I use this code to get all users and add a control i created call UserIcon for each one

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient( global::Bolts_WB.Properties.Settings.Default.acess_token);
        dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me/friends");
        foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo.data)
        {
            UserIcon x = new UserIcon(friend.name, friend.id);
            x.Size = new Size(53, 53);
            x.CreateControl();
            x.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            x.Visible = true;
         facebooklistfriends.Controls.Add(x);
    }
```

when i debug it sends an error like this :

(OAuthException) Invalid access token signature.
it is thrown in   dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me/friends");

what causes it and how can it be solved?

I am pretty sure that my access token is right because it works with my posting method

My Permissions are these

```
   private string[] _extendedPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "publish_stream", "friends_about_me", "read_mailbox",  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that the access token is correct, then try entering the URL directly in  **Firefox** browser.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ADD-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

If this gives you the proper response, then your access token is valid and the problem is else where.

Comment: i did and i got the proper respond
any other ideas?

Comment: I assume you have made sure that the code below is actually getting the accesstoken and is not empty? `global::Bolts_WB.Properties.Settings.Default.acess_token` . Also, you can use an HTTP analyzer like Fiddler or IEInspector to check that actual HTTP call made by the API is sending the correct info.

Comment: as i said it is not the accesstoken's fault i am pretty sure 100% because i have another button to post to Facebook using the same accesstoken and it works, its not the permissions either